# add_row coverts factor/numeric columns to char; cannot add ordered factors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I need to use `tibble::add_row` function to add a single row into an existing `tibble`.

```
df = tibble(cola = as.ordered(c(1, 2, 3)), colb = as.factor(c("xx", "xxx", "xxx")))
df2 = df %>% add_row(tibble_row(cola = 1, colb = as.factor("yyy")))
```

this coverts my column `cola` into a `char` variable. If I change the script into:

```
df %>% add_row(tibble_row(cola = as.ordered(1), colb = as.factor("yyy")))
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: Can't combine `..1$cola` <ordered> and `..2$cola` <ordered<5b58e>>.

I experimented with other data structures. `add_row` works well with `numeric` and `char` data formats. But, fails with `ordered`. For the new row, unless the data type is specified (like `as.factor`), `add_row` silently coverts all `factors` to `char`. The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1021). But, I cannot find a solution, such as adding an `argument` like `stringsAsFactors = T`. making the new row a `tibble` with `tibble_row()`  or `as_tibble_row()` followed by `dplyr::bind_rows()` doesn't help either as it throws the same error on the `ordered` factors.

My questions.

1. How can I stop `add_row` converting all factors to characters, without defining the data structure for  each relevant column the new row?
2. can `add_row` not deal with `ordered` factors?

Comment: What is the package version used

Comment: The types are different for the first column and in the s econd column, the levels

Comment: @akrun, 3.0.1 and 1.0.0 for 'tibble' and 'dplyr', respectively. thanks for the comment on levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the available ordered levels:

```
df %>% add_row(tibble_row(cola = ordered(1, levels = 1:3), colb = as.factor("yyy")))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  cola  colb 
  <ord> <fct>
1 1     xx   
2 2     xxx  
3 3     xxx  
4 1     yyy
```

Comment: thanks. The levels argument completely skipped my mind. I do not have enough points to  up your answer score, but, I marked it correct, at least for the Q 2.

Comment: That addressed my question 2. any idea on question 1?

Comment: @TDS the difficulty is that when you add a row, you are actually appending a single item to each of the vectors that make up the tibble. When you try to add `colb = "yyy"` you _are_ specifying the data structure: you are implicitly specifying a character type. So really, R sees that you are attempting to concatenate a character to a factor. If that string does not exist as a factor level, R will not simply add it as a factor level. It would be possible to write a wrapper for `tibble_row` that does this, but it is not part of the function's interface, and this is for good reason.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. makes sense.